# Prevent Jupyter from changing selected cell with arrows

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

In the [VSC documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_select-a-code-cell) you may read:

```
Select a code cell
The selected code cell can be changed using the mouse, the up/down arrow keys on the keyboard, and the J (down) and K (up) keys. To use the keyboard, the cell must be in command mode.
```

Having the arrows changing the selected code cell annoys me and I would like to turn off this behaviour. Very often, I press ESC one time more than needed and I end up with the code cell selected. Then I try to move the text cursor with the arrow keys and I end up in a quasi-random location of my Jupyter notebook.

If I look into the "Keyboard shortcuts" definitions, searching for "Jupyter" or for "Jupyter cell", I cannot find anything.

What do I need to do in order to change the selected code cell only with the J and K keys?

Comment: So you're not looking for the `notebook.focusPreviousEditor` and `notebook.focusNextEditor` or `jupyter.gotoNextCellInFile` and `jupyter.gotoPrevCellInFile` keybinding commands?

Comment: I modified those two mappings but unforunately nothing changed.